# Why i get 'Incorrect integer value:' on int field with allow NULL & default NULL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, null

I just changed, on **phpmyadmin**, an **int obligatory field** to not obligatory (*i ticked the empty checkbox*) and **made default values NULL**.

So far so good, 
 the problem is when i try to change this value on already exist records (**from phpmyadmin**) and delete the number value, i get a warning message :

```
Affected 0 records.
Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'fktypeId' at row 1
```

and it puts 0 on the field value.
*I dont want to have any value at all into that field, neither 0 nor NULL, just empty field*.

Can this happen? Thanks in advance.

This is definitelly a **phpmyadmin** way of manipulating the not obligatory Int fields. 
*We just have to check the checkbox!! otherwise it turns always the field value to 0*

Thanks folks, i post the printscreen for those who come up with this 'problem'.

[image]

Comment: Is the field of integer type?

Comment: Yes of course , int(11). But i see now that when i add new record (phpmyadmin) and leave the field empty , it adds NULL instead of 0.
Is it just for the edit the problem?

Comment: If the *default* is `NULL` for the field, then a newly created record will have `NULL`, *unless* a specific integer value is explicitly entered.

Comment: Storing integer value zero is the expected behavior. It's not possible to store a zero length string (or empty string) in an *integer* type column... the only possible values are integer values, or a NULL. MySQL implicitly converts any non-NULL value into an integer value. MySQL evaluates an empty string is as integer value of zero.

Answer (score 4):

An integer column can only store an integer value, or a NULL.  A zero length string cannot be "stored" in an integer column.

The warning is the expected behavior if a string value which can't be converted to an integer value is supplied for an integer column.

If you are running a SQL statement, you can use the keyword `NULL`

For example:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET some_int_col = NULL WHERE id = 42 ;
```

If you are using some kind of "row editor", then there may be a checkbox you need to select for the `NULL` value.

With a SQL statement, such as this:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET some_int_col = '' WHERE id = 42 ;
```

The literal string value (in this case, a zero length string) is being assigned to a column of integer datatype, MySQL will implicitly perform a conversion. In a numeric context, the zero length string evalutes to zero.

For comparison, consider the behavior when different strings are implicitly converted to numeric.

```
 SELECT '' AS foo,  '' + 0 AS foo_int
 UNION ALL SELECT ' b'     , ' b'      + 0
 UNION ALL SELECT '1A'     , '1A'      + 0
 UNION ALL SELECT ' 23DE78', ' 23DE78' + 0
 UNION ALL SELECT NULL     , NULL      + 0
```

returns

```
foo       foo_int  
--------  -------
                0
 b              0
1A              1
 23DE78        23
(NULL)     (NULL)
```

Comment: You are right my man, i just saw it on the phpmyadmin , but you got the point. Although my local sql manager software that i have on my PC allows me to clear the field without any checkbox. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this to the pool even though it already partly was mentioned in a previous answer:

My query was:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn='NULL';
```

when it should have been:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn=NULL;
```